# Why customize tag of sentry is not working in laravel 8?

Tags: mysql, laravel, datatable, phpmyadmin, sentry

I made middle ware for setting customize tag of login user, I want to customize tag in event Id for performance monitering.But this is not working I'm I missing something?? Need Help...

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Auth;
use Closure;
use Sentry\State\Scope;


class SentryUser
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && app()->bound('sentry'))
        {
            \Sentry\configureScope(function (Scope $scope): void {
                $scope->setTag([
                    'id'    => Auth::user()->id,
                    'email' => Auth::user()->email,
                    'name'  => Auth::user()->name,
                ]);
            });
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setTags instead of setTag?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Or use your commenting privilege to ask a clarification question in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTag` method is used to set a single tag, while the `setTags` method is used to set multiple tags.

Therefore, to set multiple tags in your SentryUser middleware, you should use the `setTags` method, as shown below:

```php
\Sentry\configureScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
    $scope->setTags([
        'id'    => Auth::user()->id,
        'email' => Auth::user()->email,
        'name'  => Auth::user()->name,
    ]);
});
```

You can also use the `setTag` method to set a single tag, as shown below:

```php
\Sentry\configureScope(function (\Sentry\State\Scope $scope): void {
    $scope->setTag('id', Auth::user()->id); 
    $scope->setTag('email', Auth::user()->email); 
    $scope->setTag('name', Auth::user()->name); 
});
```